# Função de agrupamento calculando erradamente

Tags: mysql, python

Estou tentando escrever uma função em python que toma dois vetores, elimina duplicatas no primeiro e soma os dados correspondentes no segundo.

Meio que tentando emular a seguinte consulta MySQL:

```sql
SELECT `Price`, sum(`Volume`) FROM `Dataset` GROUP BY `Price`
```

Meu código está assim:

```python
def Group(X, Y):
  temp = dict.fromkeys(X, [0, 0])
  L = range(len(X))

  for i in L:
    print('BEFORE: i=%s, temp=%s, temp[X[i]]=%s, X=%s, X[i]=%s, Y=%s, Y[i]=%s' %(i, temp, temp[X[i]], X, X[i], Y, Y[i]))

    temp[X[i]][0] += Y[i]
    temp[X[i]][1] += 1

    print('AFTER: i=%s, temp=%s, temp[X[i]]=%s, X=%s, X[i]=%s, Y=%s, Y[i]=%s' %(i, temp, temp[X[i]], X, X[i], Y, Y[i]))

  return temp
```

Ao chamar a função, ela deveria responder assim:

```
>>> a = [1, 1, 2]
>>> b = [3, 4, 5]
>>> Group(a, b)
BEFORE: i=0, temp={1: [0, 0], 2: [0, 0]}, temp[X[i]]=[0, 0], X=[1, 1, 2], X[i]=1, Y=[3, 4, 5], Y[i]=3
AFTER: i=0, temp={1: [3, 1], 2: [0, 0]}, temp[X[i]]=[3, 1], X=[1, 1, 2], X[i]=1, Y=[3, 4, 5], Y[i]=3
BEFORE: i=1, temp={1: [3, 1], 2: [0, 0]}, temp[X[i]]=[3, 1], X=[1, 1, 2], X[i]=1, Y=[3, 4, 5], Y[i]=4
AFTER: i=1, temp={1: [7, 2], 2: [0, 0]}, temp[X[i]]=[7, 2], X=[1, 1, 2], X[i]=1, Y=[3, 4, 5], Y[i]=4
BEFORE: i=2, temp={1: [7, 2], 2: [5, 1]}, temp[X[i]]=[5, 1], X=[1, 1, 2], X[i]=2, Y=[3, 4, 5], Y[i]=5
AFTER: i=2, temp={1: [7, 2], 2: [5, 1]}, temp[X[i]]=[5, 1], X=[1, 1, 2], X[i]=2, Y=[3, 4, 5], Y[i]=5
{1: [7, 2], 2: [5, 1]}
```

Mas está respondendo assim:

```
>>> a = [1, 1, 2]
>>> b = [3, 4, 5]
>>> Group(a, b)
BEFORE: i=0, temp={1: [0, 0], 2: [0, 0]}, temp[X[i]]=[0, 0], X=[1, 1, 2], X[i]=1, Y=[3, 4, 5], Y[i]=3
AFTER: i=0, temp={1: [3, 1], 2: [3, 1]}, temp[X[i]]=[3, 1], X=[1, 1, 2], X[i]=1, Y=[3, 4, 5], Y[i]=3
BEFORE: i=1, temp={1: [3, 1], 2: [3, 1]}, temp[X[i]]=[3, 1], X=[1, 1, 2], X[i]=1, Y=[3, 4, 5], Y[i]=4
AFTER: i=1, temp={1: [7, 2], 2: [7, 2]}, temp[X[i]]=[7, 2], X=[1, 1, 2], X[i]=1, Y=[3, 4, 5], Y[i]=4
BEFORE: i=2, temp={1: [7, 2], 2: [7, 2]}, temp[X[i]]=[7, 2], X=[1, 1, 2], X[i]=2, Y=[3, 4, 5], Y[i]=5
AFTER: i=2, temp={1: [12, 3], 2: [12, 3]}, temp[X[i]]=[12, 3], X=[1, 1, 2], X[i]=2, Y=[3, 4, 5], Y[i]=5
{1: [12, 3], 2: [12, 3]}
```

Já na 1ª execução do laço a função erra, pois quero que ela acrescente o valor em `Y[0]` *somente* em `temp[1][0]`, e não em `temp[2][0]` também.

Alguém consegue enxergar o que estou fazendo de errado?

Desde já agradeço!

---

[RESOLVIDO]

Quero sinceramente agradecer mais uma vez pelas dicas e respostas valiosas! A solução que escolhi/encontrei foi:

```
def Group(X, Y, isSum):
    temp = dict.fromkeys(X, (0, 0))
    for i in range(len(X)):
        temp[X[i]] = (temp[X[i]][0] + Y[i], temp[X[i]][1] + 1)
    if not isSum:
        for i in temp:
            temp[i] = temp[i][0] / temp[i][1]
    return temp
```

E a resposta da máquina foi:

```
>>> a = [1, 1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> b = [5, 6, 7, 7, 8]
>>> 
>>> Group(a, b, True)
{1: (11, 2), 2: (7, 1), 3: (7, 1), 4: (8, 1)}
>>> Group(b, a, False)
{8: 4.0, 5: 1.0, 6: 1.0, 7: 2.5}
>>>
```

Na verdade queria duas funções em uma, para emular estas duas queries:

```
SELECT `Price`, SUM(`Volume`) FROM `Dataset` GROUP BY `Price` ;
SELECT `Volume`, AVG(`Price`) FROM `Dataset` GROUP BY `Volume` ;
```

Peço desculpas ter apresentado apenas metade do problema.

Abraço a todos!

---

[RESOLVIDO 2]

Ai vai um complemento, com dados reais do problema:

```
Dataset = [
    # Tempo, Volume e Preço do par BTCUSD em [https://www.bitfinex.com/]
    (1426502898, 0.01, 292.76),
    (1426503160, 0.01, 292.77),
    (1426503169, 0.0224, 292.77),
    (1426503180, 0.304111, 292.77),
    (1426503188, 0.026, 292.77),
    (1426503194, 0.388, 292.77),
    (1426503287, 0.01, 292.76),
    (1426503287.14286, 0.202, 292.7),
    (1426503287.28571, 0.7082, 292.77),
    (1426503287.42857, 1.12, 292.75),
    (1426503287.57143, 2.57392822, 292.76),
    (1426503287.71429, 3.095, 292.77),
    (1426503287.85714, 7, 292.77),
    (1426503292, 0.22, 292.7),
    (1426503320, 0.5, 292.78),
    (1426503340, 0.5, 292.78),
    (1426503358, 0.5, 292.78),
    (1426503377, 0.01, 292.76),
    (1426503377.5, 0.49, 292.78),
    (1426503378, 0.01, 292.75),
    (1426503384, 0.01, 292.76),
    (1426503385, 0.1, 292.78),
    (1426503394, 0.01, 292.76),
    (1426503395, 0.5, 292.78),
    (1426503399, 0.01, 292.76),
    (1426503402, 0.01, 292.76),
    (1426503407, 0.01, 292.76),
    (1426503414, 0.181549, 292.78),
    (1426503414.5, 0.318451, 292.78),
    (1426503415, 0.01, 292.76)
]

partition = lambda data, pos: [i[pos] for i in data]

def Group(X, Y, isSum):
    temp = dict.fromkeys(X, (0, 0))
    for i in range(len(X)):
        temp[X[i]] = (temp[X[i]][0] + Y[i], temp[X[i]][1] + 1)
    if not isSum:
        for i in temp:
            temp[i] = temp[i][0] / temp[i][1]
    return temp
```

E a resposta da máquina foi:

```
>>> 
>>> Group(partition(Dataset, 2), partition(Dataset, 1), True)
{292.77: (11.553711, 8), 292.78: (3.09, 8), 292.76: (2.6639282199999985, 10), 292.75: (1.1300000000000001, 2), 292.7: (0.42200000000000004, 2)}
>>> Group(partition(Dataset, 1), partition(Dataset, 2), False)
{0.304111: 292.77, 1.12: 292.75, 2.57392822: 292.76, 3.095: 292.77, 0.181549: 292.78, 0.5: 292.78, 7: 292.77, 0.026: 292.77, 0.202: 292.7, 0.01: 292.76000000000005, 0.1: 292.78, 0.388: 292.77, 0.318451: 292.78, 0.49: 292.78, 0.0224: 292.77, 0.22: 292.7, 0.7082: 292.77}
>>>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema com seu código é que você está usando um objeto **mutável** como valor padrão do seu dicionário. Quando você faz:

```
temp = dict.fromkeys(X, [0, 0])
```

Você espera que ele crie uma lista `[0, 0]` *diferente* para cada chave em `X`, certo? Mas não é isso que ocorre, ele está usando **a mesma lista** para todos os elementos! Aí, naturalmente, ao modificar uma delas se modifica as outras também...

Um meio de solucionar é usando uma tupla, que é imutável:

```
temp = dict.fromkeys(X, (0, 0))

...

temp[X[i]] = (temp[X[i]][0] + Y[i], temp[X[i]][1] + 1)
```

De todo modo por que em vez disso não usar o método [`groupby`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) do Python?

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>>
>>> a = [1, 1, 2]
>>> b = [3, 4, 5]
>>>
>>> temp = {}
>>> for g,e in groupby(sorted(zip(a,b)), lambda x: x[0]):
...   e = list(e)
...   temp[g] = [sum(x[1] for x in e), len(e)]
...
>>> temp
{1: [7, 2], 2: [5, 1]}
```

Explicando:

- O `zip(a,b)` relaciona cada elemento de `a` com seu elemento correspondente de `b`, i.e. `[(1,3), (1,4), (2,5)]`;

  - O `sorted` é necessário, pois o `groupby` só funciona corretamente se a lista estiver ordenada segundo a chave de agrupamento. A ordenação padrão é suficiente, pois ele compara primeiro pelo primeiro elemento (a chave) e em seguida pelo segundo.
- O `groupby` agrupa essa lista pelo primeiro elemento; `g` então é o elemento da lista `a`, e `e` é um iterador sobre os pares agrupados;
- Para cada agrupamento, eu calculo a soma dos itens da lista `b` nesse agrupamento e o número desses itens, associando-os ao seu elemento `g`.