# Como usar um iterator duas vezes dentro de uma compreensão?

Tags: python, iterator, expressões

Digamos que eu tenha uma lista:

```
lista = [(1,1), (1,2), (1,3), (2,6), (2,4), (3,1), (3,2)]
```

E eu quero saber os valores máximo e mínimo do segundo elemento, agrupados pelo primeiro. Ou seja:

```
{ 1:(1,3), 2:(4,6), 3:(1,2) }
```

Pensei em usar uma compreensão junto com a função [`groupby`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
{ 
    a:(min(x[1] for x in b), max(x[1] for x in b))
    for a,b in groupby(sorted(lista), lambda x: x[0]) 
}
```

O problema é que o primeiro uso de `b` consome todos os elementos do iterador, de modo que o segundo uso encontra o iterador vazio:

> ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence

Pensei em criar uma lista com o iterador, ou talvez usar a função [`tee`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.tee), mas não sei como encaixar isso na compreensão sem ter de desfazê-la completamente e transformá-la num loop. Isso é possível? Como fazer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontrei duas formas, uma usando `lambda` (que só funciona para a chave ou pro valor, mas não pra ambos):

```
>>> {
...   a:(lambda b: (min(x[1] for x in b), max(x[1] for x in b)))(list(b))
...   for a,b in groupby(sorted(lista), lambda x: x[0])
... }
{1: (1, 3), 2: (4, 6), 3: (1, 2)}
```

Outro usando um outro `for` dentro da compreensão:

```
>>> {
...   a:(min(x[1] for x in c), max(x[1] for x in c))
...   for a,b in groupby(sorted(lista), lambda x: x[0])
...   for c in [list(b)]
... }
{1: (1, 3), 2: (4, 6), 3: (1, 2)}
```

Answer (score 0):

"""
Simple is better than complex.
"""

```
mylist = [(1,1), (1,2), (1,3), (2,6), (2,4), (3,1), (3,2)]
group = {}
for key, val in mylist:
    group[key] = (min(group[key][0], val), max(group[key][1], val)) if key in group else (val, val)
```

E nesse caso, o "simple" reduz bastante a aparente complexidade do que você quer fazer (não há necessidade de ordenar, nem do "groupby") ...

É feito em tres linhas, por que o foco com as lists comprehensions e similares não é diminuir a legibilidade- é ter uma forma prática e mais curta de escrever operações simples para um vetor de elementos - em particular operações envolvendo mapeamento e filtro.  Se começar a ficar complexo demais, lembre-se sempre que 
"Readability counts."

Comment: Eu discordo que uma forma declarativa seja menos legível que uma imperativa. Sei que essa segunda é mais compreensível para programadores iniciantes ("mínimo denominador comum"), mas quem já tem alguma experiência em programação funcional não deve ter muita dificuldade para entender a primeira, pelo menos não mais que a segunda (por exemplo, veja [esse trecho de código](http://pastebin.com/84wjUEVL) de um sistema que estou desenvolvendo, você tem dificuldade de entender o que ele está fazendo? E os loops que eu precisaria fazer se não pudesse usar compreensões, será que ficaria mais legível?).

Comment: De todo modo, aceito a crítica e agradeço pela sugestão alternativa. Entretanto, esse foi só um exemplo (dúvida que surgiu [ao tentar responder uma outra pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/55030/215)), eu estava interessado numa resposta genérica para esse problema (usar o mesmo iterador duas vezes sem consumi-lo, e sem poder usar uma variável auxiliar), e isso não responde ao que foi perguntado.